# Can I wire a Bathroom Fan to two Switches in Parallel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, home-automation

I want to control a bathroom exhaust fan with a wall timer, and a 24 vac relay. Basically both switches would be wired in parallel. Is this safe to do?

[image: Wiring]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Switches wired in parallel like that won't function as switches as all - you'll have a hot unless *both of them* are off.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I want the fan _on_ when either or both switches are on. The only time the fan would be off is if _both_ switches are _off_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing electrically wrong with this, as long as no other part of the electrical code in your region is violated.  For example you can't over-stuff the junction box.  And your relay has to be rated for, and not get too hot, if used 24/7.

You can also do this with off the shelf home control components.

Note your ground needs to connect to the box frame and probably the timer frame, in accordance with normal electrical installation procedures.  The relay is is not touchable by humans and need not be grounded.

Comment: Would a relay like this suffice? Could a relay be mounted in the same box as the timer switch? http://www.ebay.com/itm/OMRON-G2R-1A-T-AC24-Relay-4-Pins-Spno-/221377982832?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item338b27f170

Comment: The OMRON G2R-1A-T-AC24 seems fine.  24VAC relay.  Can switch up to 7 amps inductive (you get an inductive kick from the motor).  The Coil VA Rating gives you a hint at how hot the thing will get in your box (this is an AC only coil, it will burn up if fed DC).

Comment: @rmkilc -- the main problem with relays like that is that they don't carry a full UL listing, just UL component recognition.  You'll need something like [this relay-in-a-box](http://www.grainger.com/product/FUNCTIONAL-DEVICES-INC-RIB-Enclosed-Pre-Wired-Relay-5LE35?s_pp=false&picUrl=//static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/5LE35_AS01?$smthumb$) instead

Answer (score 0):

rmkilc, what you want to do in principle is FINE. Only you do not need any relays or anything fancy. You can wire the 120V circuit with two switches in parallel. This is done all the time with FanTec (remote motor) type fans.

I typically have a junction box near the fan and run two switch loops down, one to each room.

Comment: This answer misses the point: he wants to hook the other switch to a furnace.